# InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "all"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**I know "all" isn't an integer**

I took this method of the official documentation postgres + rails (I can't link it now but might later if needed)

```
def list
  @a = a.find(:all)
end
```

so I thought it would list every "a" in "a" table, but didn't. Instead that error was thrown. Isn't this the way rails+gres works? Help a newbie please, thank you vm

Comment: What documentation did you read this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` accepts an integer and finds the record with the given int ID.

If you want to retrieve all records, use:

```
def list
  @a = A.all
end
```

Assuming that `A` is a model